# Unable to create new table in SQLite, getting error near table name

Tags: sqlite

Can anyone figure out what the error is while I am creating a new table in SQLite? There is some error near the transaction.

```
CREATE TABLE transaction 
(
     id INTEGER, 
     user_id INTEGER, 
     shares INTEGER NOT NULL,
     time TEXT NOT NULL, 
     price TEXT NOT NULL, 
     symbol TEXT NOT NULL, 

     PRIMARY KEY(id),
     FOREIGN KEY(user_id) REFERENCES users(id)
);
```

Comment: "transaction" is a [SQLite keyword](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html) (reserved word).

Comment: thank you soo much

Comment: Hi Tanish, so we can make this question useful to others too would you copy paste into the question the exact error text?

Comment: what do you mean i didin't understand?